# mod_rewrite() too many internal redirects

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have successfully implemented the basic facebook like URLs:

http://example.com/(username) which internally calls http://example.com/sites/(username)
using the following mod_rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)$ sites/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Please note that the (username) folder exists inside the sites folder

The above works perfectly fine. But now i want to prettify my other urls like:
http://example.com/(username)/Image/2/ this should internally call http://example.com/sites/(username)/index.php?type=image&id=2

To do this i added the following code in the second last line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/Image/(.*)$ /sites/$1/index.php?type=image&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

I was hoping the [L] at the end will stop the rule from being computed after this. But from the logs it turns out it goes into an infinite loop and is truncated.

Can someone point out what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your DocumentRoot folder you can have this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ sites/$1/index.php?type=$2*id=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!sites[^/]+)(/.*)?$ sites/$1$2 [NC,L]
```